# How do I plot two sparklines in the same cell in Ag-Grid?

Tags: ag-grid

I am trying to plot two sparklines in the same cell within an AgGrid table

Similar to this:

[image]

I imagine it could be done with a CellRenderer, but keen to know what's the simple way to re-use Ag-Grid's excellent Sparkline functionality.

I did not find any setting within the Ag-Grid sparkline renderer to enable this.

I tried to generate the plots using stand-alone plotting libraries (eg. Plotly) but the performance is terrible compared to AgGrid.